# How to apply metallic map and preserve the non metallic parts?

Tags: baking

I've baked a metallic map for a sword and it sort of works, but if I reduce roughness to make it look more metallic, the grip part of the mesh, which is supposed to be leather, gets shiny also and looks unrealistic. What's a way around this?

Comment: If your sword has to be 1 material, there's nothing to stop you making a roughness map, too.

Comment: I can't believe how simple that was. Thanks.